# Batch Script Comparison

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I am doing a comparison using a batch script, i can search for a string and it successfully states if it exists or not, but i am having trouble when my string has two sections: Please see code below,

```
@ECHO off

SET key0="First Number"="1000"

SET key1="First Number"
SET key2==
SET key3="1000"

SET key4=%key1%%key2%%key3%

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a in (FILE.TXT) do call :processline %%a

findstr /X %key4% FILE.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (

ECHO Key Exists
) ELSE (
ECHO NO
)
PAUSE
goto :eof
```

If i search for key0 or key4 i get the result NO. But if i search for key1, key2 or key3 i get Key Exists....

Any ideas on how i search for string containing two separate words in quotes?

Comment: Please edit your question to better explain. What is `:processline`? What is "failing" - :processline or findstr? What does the line look like that is supposed to match? Make sure to clearly show examples of code that work, and examples that do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution is:

```
@ECHO off

SET key0=\"First Number\"=\"1000\"

SET key1=\"First Number\"
SET key2==
SET key3=\"1000\"

SET key4=%key1%%key2%%key3%

findstr /X /C:"%key4%" FILE.TXT
if %errorlevel%==0 (
   ECHO Key Exists
) ELSE (
   ECHO NO
)
PAUSE
```

1. Each double quote in the search string must be escaped with a backslash.
2. Option `/C:` must be used for a literal string search instead of a regular expression search.
3. The entire search string itself must be in double quotes because of containing a space character.

I used the documentation of [Findstr](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) by Microsoft and help of this command output in a command prompt window after entering `findstr /?`